# How to helm lookup to lookup a specific resource and if found dont install it

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have  my-service.yaml resource
and
I want to use Helm lookup and  check if this service exists or not:

1- If found, it shouldn't be installed again inside the helm chart and should be excluded.

2- If not found, the helm install should install it.

I don't know how to write this code down in the helper.tpl file

this was my trial

```
{{- define "install.service" -}}
{{- $service := lookup "v1" "Service" .Release.Namespace "shopping-service-{{ .Values.app.name }}" -}}
{{- if $service -}}
{{/* 
    Code of reusing existing service data 
*/}}

{{- else -}}
{{/*
    Install the service.yaml 
*/}}

{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: A better approach might be to give it a unique name like `{{ .Release.Name }}-shopping` and unconditionally install it.  Having a duplicate Service isn't especially harmful.  What should happen if the externally-created Service is deleted; what should happen if this chart chooses to install it, but then the external process tries to recreate it as well?